# "Unknown argument: nlpanalytics" error while running botium-cli

Tags: automated-tests, bots, chatbot

While exploring the **Botium** documentation in [the Botium GitHub page](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-cli), I found a useful command line switch '**nlpanalytics**' for **botium-cli**.

However, I get the error "Unknown argument: nlpanalytics" when I try it.

Is there a dependency I am missing?

While running it, I **do** have .convo files and a valid botium.json in context.

Thanks a ton!

Have a botful day!!

```
c:\botium\cli-build>botium-cli nlpanalytics
Botium CLI

Usage: botium-cli.js [options]

Commands:
  botium-cli.js run [output]               Run Botium convo files and output
                                           test report with Mocha test runner
  botium-cli.js alexaimport                Importing conversations for Botium
  botium-cli.js dialogflowimport [source]  Importing conversations for Botium
  botium-cli.js watsonimport [source]      Importing conversations for Botium
  botium-cli.js emulator [ui]              Launch Botium emulator
  botium-cli.js box [output]               Run Test Project on Botium Box and
                                           output test report with Mocha test
                                           runner
  botium-cli.js init                       Setup a directory for Botium usage
  botium-cli.js init-alexa-avs             Run the "Botium Connector Alexa AVS
                                           Initialization Tool"
  botium-cli.js init-dev [project]         Setup a development project for
                                           Botium connectors, asserters or logic
                                           hooks in the current directory
  botium-cli.js inbound-proxy              Run Botium endpoint for accepting
                                           inbound messages, forwarding it to
                                           Redis
  botium-cli.js agent                      Launch Botium agent

Options:
  --help, -h     Show help                                             [boolean]
  --version, -V  Show version number                                   [boolean]
  --verbose, -v  Enable verbose output (also read from env variable
                 "BOTIUM_VERBOSE" - "1" means verbose)[boolean] [default: false]
  --convos, -C   Path to a directory holding your convo files. Can be specified
                 more than once, ending in "--" ("... --convos dir1 dir2 dir3 --
                 ...") (also read from env variables starting with
                 "BOTIUM_CONVOS")                         [array] [default: "."]
  --config, -c   Path to the Botium configuration file (also read from env
                 variable "BOTIUM_CONFIG")            [default: "./botium.json"]

Unknown argument: nlpanalytics
```

Comment: Hi, if I saw it correctly from the help output there is indeed no `nlpanalytics` command. So you may want to read [this article for nlu chatbot training](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/quality-metrics-for-nlu-chatbot-training-data-part-1-confusion-matrix-91ac71b90270?) first

Comment: Thanks @Vall0n The article is useful and can be tried out in Botium Box.
However I want to check if the same capability is available in botium-cli as well, as shown in their doc here: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-cli#botium-cli-nlpanalytics-

Comment: Hi @cethie, which version of `botium-cli` do you use? Is it up to date? Because your version does not contain the `nlpanalytics` command. But on the GitHub page it is mentioned as you already pointed out.

Comment: there has been a delay with publishing the latest release. while nlpanalytics is already part of the code base, the npm packages and docker images are not yet updated.

Comment: Thanks a ton @FlorianTreml for clarifying. 
I can see the analytics reports works great in Box.. I can wait for it to be added to npm. Have a great day!